# git error: "Add Remote Repository: '/data/www/examplesite' does not appear to be a git repository"

Tags: git, smartgit

I've used a local instance of git (via SmartGit) for a few years (using secure FTP to the remote server).  That workflow does the job but I want to move into the modern age and push my updates directly to the remote server.

First, on the remote box:

```
[acoder@remote www]# mkdir buymystuffs.com
[acoder@remote www]# cd buymystuffs.com/
[acoder@remote buymystuffs.com]# git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /data/www)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
[acoder@remote buymystuffs.com]# git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /data/www/buymystuffs.com/.git/
[acoder@remote buymystuffs.com]# git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Now on the local system I set up a new repo using

[image]

Smartgit Log:

```
[master (root-commit) bd5a85f] initial commit
/storage/web/git/buymystuffs.com> git commit --allow-empty --file=/tmp/smartgit-2242088229372859523tmp/commit-95902291203419258.tmp
/storage/web/git/buymystuffs.com> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /storage/web/git/buymystuffs.com/.git/
```

Next I try to get the local and remote repos talking:

[image]

Then enter my details here:

[image]

Clicking Add produces the following error:

> Add Remote Repository: '/data/www/buymystuffs.com' does not appear to
>   be a git repository Could not read from remote repository.: Please
>   make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I've confirmed that I have permissions to the remote directory:

```
[acoder@remote www]# ll
total 0
drwxrwx---.  3 apache webdev  18 May 11 15:51 buymystuffs.com
```

*(user acoder is a member of the webdev group)*

I also tried setting up the remote tree with `git init --bare`.  That let me get past the erros above.  When I updated a new local document, I did not see an option to Commit and Push.  I could only Commit.  I tried that, then checked the remote tree and found this:

```
[acoder@remote buymystuffs.com]$ ll /data/www/buymystuffs.com
total 12
drwxrwxr-x. 2 acoder acoder   6 May 14 10:32 branches
-rw-rw-r--. 1 acoder acoder  66 May 14 10:32 config
-rw-rw-r--. 1 acoder acoder  73 May 14 10:32 description
-rw-rw-r--. 1 acoder acoder  23 May 14 10:32 HEAD
drwxrwxr-x. 2 acoder acoder 242 May 14 10:32 hooks
drwxrwxr-x. 2 acoder acoder  21 May 14 10:32 info
drwxrwxr-x. 4 acoder acoder  30 May 14 10:32 objects
drwxrwxr-x. 4 acoder acoder  31 May 14 10:32 refs
```

Instead of the index.html document I attempted to commit.

What step(s) am I missing to be able to work locally then push commits to the remote repo set up above?

Comment: You should do a `bare` repo in order to be able to push/pull from it. A git repo created with `git init` is a working repo; one created with `git init --bare` creates a repository as a "holder".

Comment: Can you access the remote repository from command line using `git ls-remote <URL>`?

Comment: @muecas, removed and recreated remote directory buymystuffs.com, then issued `git init --bare`.  That returned "Initialized empty Git repository".   When I check status of the same directory I am showing:  `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

Comment: Ok, a bare repo is only to store the repository itself. You should then  add some hooks to checkout the work to a working directory. Do you want me to explain how to do that? I can write an answer on that. In a few words, you need to set up your git repo outside the document root. Then when pushing, the content of the repo should be cjecked out to the document root (so it gets published).

Comment: Went ahead and continued steps above, and successfully added the remote repo.   Please add your comment as an answer so others can more easily find it.

Comment: And you successfully pushed content to the document root?

Comment: Hang off on the answer there is an issue.

Comment: Added steps of `git init --bare` and subsequent `commit`, and resulting remote directory listing to my question.

Comment: It dawned on me that this may be doing exactly what my question is technically asking - pushing commits to a remote repository.   I'm wondering if there is a way (or if this is a bad idea) to push commits directly to the active web server document directory?  That's what I was trying to ask, but clearly got my wording wrong.

Comment: This appears to be what I am pecking for: http://toroid.org/git-website-howto

Comment: Yes, that example will work at a glance. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171017/discussion-between-muecas-and-a-coder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, the answer is that I am unable to make git do what I want it to do.  Both /home and the /data/www directories (and /var) are marked `noexec` which rules out a post-update hook to [push & deploy](http://krisjordan.com/essays/setting-up-push-to-deploy-with-git).

We're unable to remove `noexec`, so I am kind of out of luck.  If you have a workable solution that lets me do this in a `noexec` environment please follow up.

Thanks to SO user [muecas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9503418/muecas) for the helpful conversation.